# No scroll in Custom FooterBarLayout to Follow AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have following CoordinatorLayout behavior :

```
public class FooterBarBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FooterBarLayout> {
    //Required to instantiate as a default behavior
    public FooterBarBehavior() {
    }

    //Required to attach behavior via XML
    public FooterBarBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    //This is called to determine which views this behavior depends on
    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent,
                                   FooterBarLayout child,
                                   View dependency) {
        //We are watching changes in the AppBarLayout
        return getDependentView((ViewPager) dependency) instanceof AppBarLayout;
    }

    //This is called for each change to a dependent view
    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent,
                                          FooterBarLayout child,
                                          View dependency) {
        int offset = -getDependentView((ViewPager) dependency).getTop();
        child.setTranslationY(offset);
        return true;
    }

    private View getDependentView(ViewPager viewPager) {
        int index = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        MainPagerAdapter adapter = ((MainPagerAdapter)viewPager.getAdapter());
        ContactsFragment fragment = (ContactsFragment) adapter.getItem(index);
        if(fragment.getView() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);
    }
}
```

Here is FooterBarLayout :

```
@CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior(FooterBarBehavior.class)
public class FooterBarLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    public FooterBarLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FooterBarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FooterBarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

It has been used in the layout as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.sample.android.contact.widget.FooterBarLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.sample.android.contact.widget.ListenableTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/triangle"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_triangle_bottom_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/triangle_shape"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </com.sample.android.contact.widget.FooterBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I expect that FooterBarLayout follow AppBarLayout in the fragment and hide/show based on scroll direction. The idea is taken from : https://github.com/devunwired/coordinated-effort/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/coordinatedeffort/behaviors/FooterBarBehavior.java

But there will be no scrolling in FooterBarLayout. Do you guys have any idea to resolve this?